# Missing Quick Launch List item when creating new .aspx

Tags: quick-launch

I created a new aspx page and I'm missing the quick launch menu list. I navigate through the elements , i can only find the ul tag but inside is empty.

The code to my aspx is [here](https://codeshare.io/5XLvNM)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your page layout. Some of the layouts don't include the Quick Launch control.